# Microsoft Graph - Planner API in a Service

Tags: asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api

Im trying to make a little .core service to keep gitlab issue's and a board on Microsoft Planner in sync.

Gitlab side isn't an issue however talking to the planner aspect is proving problematic.

In Azure I have successfully added an App Registration and using the delegated permissions, I can do what I need, BUT when it gets the access token, I get the old

```
To sign in, use a web browser to open the page https://microsoft.com/devicelogin and enter the code ******** to authenticate.
```

Which as im trying to make this into a service, isn't great.

I then setup permission as a deamon but Planner dosn't allow assess to 'Application Permissions' which planner needs.

So is there another option?

Comment: For example if you create a new Plannerplan then it works only with delegated permissions. It's not exposed with application permissions so that you can use it in daemon app. Unfortunately this is by design or in other words, it will work only with delegated permissions only at this point.

Comment: So is there a way I can use delegated permissions from a service?, for example create a new user who can just connect without having website, so service can run without user input (if that idea makes sense)    no idea if idea is possible, was just a thinking out loud example

Comment: Unfortunately it won't work that way, but you may want to give a try. Being said that i would suggest you to file an Microsoft Uservoice or [upvote an existing uservoice item talks about it](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/17719684-allow-access-to-planner-using-client-credentials-f) - so that they can consider  implementing it as a feature which support application permissions. If you do so, share it here, so others can upvote it. Also it can be useful to others in the community as well :)

Comment: Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Planner does not support Application Permissions. You can try to use a user account specifically created to act as your service as a workaround. There is currently no timeline for Planner supporting Application Permissions, however this is in our work backlog.

Answer (score 0):

- For example if you create a new Plannerplan then it works only with delegated permissions. It's not exposed with application permissions so that you can use it in daemon app. Unfortunately this is by design or in other words, it will work only with delegated permissions only at this point.
- Unfortunately it won't work that way, but you may want to give a try. Being said that i would suggest you to file an Microsoft Uservoice or [upvote an existing uservoice item](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/17719684-allow-access-to-planner-using-client-credentials-f) talks about it - so that they can consider implementing it as a feature which support application permissions
- Also you can see above @Tarkan confirmed the same and shared insight that its in their backlog too.